# VSCode cannot run flutter app after upgrading Flutter to release 1.20.0 and VSCode Flutter plugin to 1.13.1

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-plugin

Using MacOS and VSCode. Just upgraded Flutter to release 1.20.0 and now I cannot start my project in debug mode (F5) from within VSCode on my iPhone simulator.

If I execute on the terminal

```
flutter run
```

everything is working as expected.

Output of flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0 at /Applications/flutter
    • Framework revision 840c9205b3 (12 hours ago), 2020-08-04 20:55:12 -0700
    • Engine revision c8e3b94853
    • Dart version 2.9.0

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/abibiano/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • C2027E6D-0C59-4B06-94BC-12382916EE09 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fixed.

Please update the vscode plugin for dart.

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2702